# Is there any inbuilt way to join sagas

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, saga

I want to run sagas,  one after another for any dispatched action. Below is a stream lined version of what I am trying to do

```
function* handleActionSaga(props){
    yield validateToken();
    yield fetchFeeds()
}
yield takeLatest('GET_FEEDS', handleActionSaga);
```

I have written a utility to avoid writing `handleActionSaga` again and again, for `actions` where I just want to validate token before going to next saga

```
function join(sagas){
    return function* (props){
        for(let saga of sagas){
            yield saga(props)
        }
    }
}


yield takeLatest('GET_FEEDS', join([validateToken,fetchFeeds]));
```

Question: Is there any in built utility provided by Redux-saga to mimic the join thing

Comment: have you tried using `all`?

Comment: I tried. Could you explain how to use it. I may have done it in wrong way

Comment: I dont know if this would work but see if this resolves `all[validateToken(), fetchFeeds()]`. I'm not sure because based on the signature of `takeLatest` it seems  it needs `HelperFunction` and `all` is an effect

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**Join**](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#jointask) in sagas to chain them by passing as function params.

Have a look at this documentation: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#jointask